# Best way to ask if a person lacks a criminal record in a form on a website

Tags: negation, legalese, ambiguity, formality

I have a website and there's an online form to be filled out by people who visit the site. I want to make sure that a certain person lacks a criminal record (that he hasn't one). So I put this:
Lack of a criminal record   YES   NO
If a person chooses YES (default) then it means that he has no criminal record and if he chooses NO, then it means that he has one. Correct?
Also the reason why I'm asking is because at first I put it like this:
Clean criminal record    YES   NO
Then I thought that it's probably wrong. Because in this case even if a person chooses YES, it would mean that a person had a criminal record once, but not anymore. Though it's more of a legal question maybe.

Comment: Please be careful when asking questions on ELL. Questions like "Best way to..." are generally "primarily opinion-based" ([off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) and might be closed.

Comment: Have you ever been convicted of a felony? "Clean criminal record?" is asking for trouble, although it is perfectly idiomatic. It's argot that has made its way into the vernacular. The rap sheet was "clean", i.e. empty.

Comment: I think the issue is solved more easily if you rephrase the form.  Why would you ask someone if they have a a *lack* of something?  Why not just ask "Do you have a criminal record?"  That's much less easily confused.

Comment: Or, *can you get a copy of your police records (police certificate)*?

Comment: Surely there's something on UX stackexchange for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

It is a legal question, but there's a more subtle issue here:

I *know* you *want* the answer to be "I don't have a criminal record", but you need to ask the opposite:

> Do you have a criminal record?

This is because the opposite question can leave "wiggle room" for the answerer, just like you feared. They could say all sorts of things (after the fact) if you try to be "nice" in the way you ask the question.

And whatever you do, do **NOT** have a default answer! If you do, and someone submits "No", then they can complain that the website answered the question for them. You need them to *positively* click either "Yes" or "No".